# What's the proper loop control structure to give the correct output?

Tags: c#, datatable, system.data.datatable

I'am trying to prepare a scheduling algorithm where i have used 3 DataTables in order to hold lecturer details panel details and hall availability details. I am using for loops to access DataTables. I found that for loop control structure doesn't help me in this situation to give the correct output

Here is my SQL statements for create tables

```
create table Lecturer_availability(
lecid int,
name varchar(100),
dat1 varchar(100),
time1 varchar(100),
dat2 varchar(100),
time2 varchar(100),
dat3 varchar(100),
time3 varchar(100),
)

create table panel(
groupid int,
e1 int,     //examiner 1
e2 int,     //examiner 2
sup int,    //supervisor   
)

create table Location_availability(
hname varchar(100),
dat1 varchar(100),
time1 varchar(100),
dat2 varchar(100),
time2 varchar(100),
dat3 varchar(100),
time3 varchar(100),
)


create table Schedule(
Location varchar(100),
Group_ID varchar(100),
Date varchar(100),
Time_slot varchar(100),
Examiner_1 varchar(100),
Examiner_2 varchar(100),
Supervisor varchar(100),
)
```

In the c# code i'm creating 3 DataTable and using the for loops i match the lectures avaiable dates and times with the hall available dates and times and insert the verified records to schedule table. panel table holds lecture id's of lecturers

This is my algorithm. Here i consider about date1 and time1 only

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

 //Load panel details    

            var panel = new DataTable();
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM panel",connString))
            {
                da.Fill(panel);

            }

             //Load lecturer avaialability

            var lecavaial = new DataTable();
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Lecturer_availability", connString))
            {
                da.Fill(lecavaial);

            }

             //Hall Availability

            var hallavaial = new DataTable();
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Location_availability", connString))
            {
                da.Fill(hallavaial);

            }

 string ex1date1, ex1time1, ex2date1, ex2time1, supdate1, suptime1;
            string ex1name, ex2name, sup, hall, groupid, date, time;

            for (int j = 0; j < hallavaial.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < panel.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lecavaial.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (panel.Rows[k]["e1"].ToString() == lecavaial.Rows[i]["lecid"].ToString())
                        {
                            ex1date1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["dat1"].ToString();
                            ex1time1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["time1"].ToString();

                            if (ex1date1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["dat1"].ToString())
                            {
                                if (ex1time1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["time1"].ToString())
                                {
                                    ex1name = lecavaial.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                                    Label5.Text = ex1name;


                                    if (panel.Rows[k]["e2"].ToString() == lecavaial.Rows[i]["lecid"].ToString())
                                    {
                                        ex2date1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["dat1"].ToString();
                                        ex2time1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["time1"].ToString();

                                        if (ex2date1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["dat1"].ToString())
                                        {
                                            if (ex2time1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["time1"].ToString())
                                            {
                                                ex2name = lecavaial.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                                                Label6.Text = ex2name;

                                                if (panel.Rows[k]["sup"].ToString() == lecavaial.Rows[i]["lecid"].ToString())
                                                {
                                                    supdate1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["dat1"].ToString();
                                                    suptime1 = lecavaial.Rows[i]["time1"].ToString();

                                                    if (supdate1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["dat1"].ToString())
                                                    {
                                                        if (suptime1 == hallavaial.Rows[j]["time1"].ToString())
                                                        {
                                                            sup = lecavaial.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                                                            Label7.Text = sup;
                                                        }

                                                    }


                                                }

                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }

                        hall = hallavaial.Rows[j]["hname"].ToString();
                        groupid = panel.Rows[k]["gid"].ToString();
                        date = lecavaial.Rows[i]["dat1"].ToString();
                        time = lecavaial.Rows[i]["time1"].ToString();
                        ex1name = Label5.Text;
                        ex2name = Label6.Text;
                        sup = Label7.Text;


                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Schedule (Location,Group_ID,Date,Time_slot,Examiner_1,Examiner_2,Supervisor) VALUES (@loc, @gid, @date, @time, @ex1, @ex2, @sup)");
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = connection;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", hall);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gid", groupid);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex1", ex1name);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex2", ex2name);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup", sup);
                            connection.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

This is how i should have my output

[image: Schedule table after comparisons]

Comment: Your db structure is somewhat questionable.  Why are all of the fields except id fields varchar?  Why don't the field names in any way describe what the field is going to store?  Some of what you are trying to accomplish could be aided by SQL queries against your DB, but you're going to need to improve the design of the DB substantially.

Comment: It is probably much easier to do all of this in a single SQL query with JOIN statements.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Extrapolating this statement: "loop control structure doesn't help me in this situation to give the correct output" yields a question of, "What's the proper loop control structure to give the correct output?", which isn't answerable as we don't know what the correct output is supposed to be.

Comment: The use of a triple nested for loop is.... terrifying. That should have been your first clue this is the wrong approach.

Comment: @returnsvoid can you suggest a way